# How to get the attribute value of the closest element

Tags: javascript, html

Here i have HTML structure and the same structure may repeat number of times with the same class names. what i'm trying to do is once i click on the `.innerDiv` i should be able to access the `attr` value of the `.inid` close to its parent element.

here is what i have tried, but its not working. i also tried adding the classname to the element i'm trying to get the value from. but its adding the class to all the element with `.inid`. how can i do this?

HTML

```
<div class="parent_div">
<div class="content-container">
   <div class="second-most-innerdiv>
     <div class="container-box">
        <div class="innerDiv">Click here</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="inid" data-attr="jkoadoas-Kjksjfks_skaj"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent_div">
<div class="content-container">
   <div class="second-most-innerdiv>
     <div class="container-box">
        <div class="innerDiv">Click here</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="inid" data-attr="jkoadoas-Kjksjfks_skaj"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(this).on('click',function(){
    $('.innerDiv').parents().find('.inid').addClass('testclass');
    $('.innerDiv').parents().find('.inid').attr(data-attr);
});
```

Comment: Jquery closest -> https://api.jquery.com/closest/   ............ 
   $('.innerDiv').closest('.parent_div').find('.inid').attr('data-attr')

Comment: also missing the dot for the innerDiv selector: `$('.innerDiv')` instead of `$('innerDiv')`

Comment: The `.inid` isn't a parent though. You need to find the closest parent with class `content-container` then take the next sibling with class `inid` [EDIT: or what @daddygames said]

Comment: FYI, [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is also a native DOM getter in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use index of innerDiv and add class-testclass to element with class- inid

1. Find index of clicked **innerDiv**  using **index('.innerDiv)**
2. Use that index to add class using **eq**
3. Add some sample css to testclass for testing
4. Syntax error in your code - closing quotes missing for class- **second-most-innerdiv**

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/

working example

```js
$('.innerDiv').on('click',function(){
    $('.inid').eq($(this).index('.innerDiv')).addClass('testclass');
console.log($('.inid').eq($(this).index('.innerDiv')).attr('data-attr'))
});
```

```css
.testclass{
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  width:10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_div">
<div class="content-container">
   <div class="second-most-innerdiv">
     <div class="container-box">
        <div class="innerDiv">Click here</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="inid" data-attr="jkoadoas-Kjksjfks_skaj"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent_div">
<div class="content-container">
   <div class="second-most-innerdiv>
     <div class="container-box">
        <div class="innerDiv">Click here</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="inid" data-attr="jkoadoas-Kjksjfks_skaj"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery closest() feature to find the parent div, then find the element with class "inid" within that parent element and get the value of the attribute.

```
$('.innerDiv').on('click',function(){
    var inid = $(this).closest('.parent_div').find('.inid');
    inid.addClass('testclass');
    console.log('selected -> ' + inid.attr(data-attr));
});
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/closest/